# ANTLR parsing MismatchedTokenException

Tags: python, antlr, parser-generator, antlrworks

I'm trying to write a simple parser for an even simpler language that I'm writing. It's composed of postfix expressions. As of now, I'm having issues with the parser. When I run it on the input `2 2 * test >>` I get a MismatchedTokenException.

Also, how would I go about implementing a recursive postfix parser?

Here's my code:

```
grammar star;

options {
    language=Python;
    output=AST;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

tokens {DECL;}
//start
//  :   decl ;
//decl
//  :   type ID -> ^(DECL type ID)
//  ;

program
    :   (body)+
    ;

body    :   (nested WS)*
    |   (var WS)*
    |   (get WS)*
    ;

var
    :   nested ID '>>'
    ;

get
    :   ID '<<'
    ;

//expressions

term
    :   INT
    ;

expr
    :   term (term operator)*
    ;

nested
    :   expr (expr operator)*
    ;

operator 
    :   ('*' | '+' | '/' | '%' | '-')
    ;

ID
    :   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ('a..z' | '0'..'9' | 'A'..'Z')*
    ;

INT
    :   '0'..'9'+
    ;

WS
    :   (' ' | '\n' | '\t' | '\r') {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

Comment: It cannot handle `3 4 * 2 3 + /` which would mean it cannot take expressions as terms.

Comment: How are you running your tests? With ANTLRWorks? With what rule did you parse `2 2 * test >>`? `start` or `program`?

Comment: I ran it in the ANTLRWorks interpreter, yes, and I parsed it with `program`

Comment: I also get some warnings about `multiple alternatives`

Comment: Your `program` and `operator` rules are ambiguous: they can match certain rules in more than one way. So while this may produce a lexer and parser, whatever you're parsing with this parser will not go as you had planned. First get this ambiguities resolved.

Comment: There are quite a few things wrong with the grammar you posted. I'll try to explain later this evening (if someone else doesn't do so before me).

Comment: I'd very much appreciate that. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things are not correct:

### 1

You've put the `WS` token on the `HIDDEN` channel, which makes them unavailable to parser rules. So all `WS` tokens inside your `body` rule are incorrect.

### 2

_(<s>your latest edit removed the left-recursion issue, but I'll still make a point of it</s> sorry, your *[other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347692/antlr-grammar-postfix)* has a left recursive rule (`expr`), so I'll leave this info in here)_

ANTLR is an [LL parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser)-generator, so you can'r create left-recursive grammars. The following is left recursive:

```
expr
  :  term term operator
  ;

term
  :  INT
  |  ID
  |  expr
  ;
```

because the first `term` inside the `expr` rule could possible match an `expr` rule itself. Like any LL parser, ANTLR generated parser cannot cope with left recursion.

### 3

If you fix the `WS` issue, your `body` rule will produce the following error message:

```
(1/7) Decision can match input such as "INT" using multiple alternatives
```

This means that the parser cannot "see" to which rule the `INT` token belongs. This is due to the fact that all your `body` alternative can be repeated zero or more times and `expr` and `nested` are also repeated. And all of them can match an `INT`, which is what ANTLR is complaining about. If you remove the `*`'s like this:

```
body
    :   nested
    |   var
    |   get
    ;

// ...

expr
    :   term (term operator)
    ;

nested
    :   expr (expr operator)
    ;
```

the errors would disappear (although that would still not cause your input to be parsed properly!).

I realize that this might still sound vague, but it's not trivial to explain (or comprehend if you're new to all this).

### 4

To properly account for recursive `expr` inside `expr`, you'll need to stay clear of left recursion as I explained in **#2**. You can do that like this:

```
expr
  :  term (expr operator | term operator)*
  ;
```

which is still ambiguous, but that is in case of describing a postfix expression using an LL grammar, unavoidable AFAIK. To resolve this, you could enable global backtracking inside the `options { ... }` section of the grammar:

```
options {
  language=Python;
  output=AST;
  backtrack=true;
}
```

### Demo

A little demo of how to parse recursive expressions could look like:

```java
grammar star;

options {
  language=Python;
  output=AST;
  backtrack=true;
}

parse
  :  expr EOF -> expr
  ;

expr
  :  (term -> term) ( expr2 operator -> ^(operator $expr expr2) 
                    | term operator  -> ^(operator term term)
                    )*
  ;

expr2 
  :  expr
  ;

term
  :  INT
  |  ID
  ;

operator 
  :  ('*' | '+' | '/' | '%' | '-')
  ;

ID
  :  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ('a..z' | '0'..'9' | 'A'..'Z')*
  ;

INT
  :  '0'..'9'+
  ;

WS
  :  (' ' | '\n' | '\t' | '\r') {$channel=HIDDEN;}
  ;
```

The test script:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import antlr3
from antlr3 import *
from antlr3.tree import *
from starLexer import *
from starParser import *

def print_level_order(tree, indent):
  print '{0}{1}'.format('   '*indent, tree.text)
  for child in tree.getChildren():
    print_level_order(child, indent+1)

input = "5 1 2 + 4 * + 3 -"
char_stream = antlr3.ANTLRStringStream(input)
lexer = starLexer(char_stream)
tokens = antlr3.CommonTokenStream(lexer)
parser = starParser(tokens)
tree = parser.parse().tree 
print_level_order(tree, 0)
```

produces the following output:

```
-
   +
      5
      *
         +
            1
            2
         4
   3
```

which corresponds to the following AST:

[image]

Comment: there is no left recursion in the original grammar

Comment: @Gene, yes, you are correct. I assumed he edited it out, but it was the OP's [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347692/antlr-grammar-postfix) where `expr` is left recursive. Thanks, I'll fix that in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your body rule never terminates, because it's allowed to match nothing. I didn't fire up ANTLR, I really don't like to mess with it, instead I rewrote your grammar in C++ (using AXE parser generator), added print statements to trace the matches and got the following result from parsing `"2 2 * test >>"`:

```
parsed term: 2
parsed expr: 2
parsed nested: 2
parsed term: 2
parsed expr: 2
parsed nested: 2
parsed body: 2 2
parsed body:
parsed body: ... here goes your infinite loop
```

If you are interested in debugging this test case, the AXE grammar is shown below, set breakpoints at prints to step through the parser:

```
using namespace axe;
typedef std::string::iterator It;

auto space = r_any(" \t\n\r");
auto int_rule = r_numstr();
auto id = r_ident();
auto op = r_any("*+/%-");
auto term = int_rule 
    >> e_ref([](It i1, It i2)
{ 
    std::cout << "\nparsed term: " << std::string(i1, i2); 
});
auto expr = (term & *(term & op)) 
    >> e_ref([](It i1, It i2)
{ 
    std::cout << "\nparsed expr: " << std::string(i1, i2); 
});
auto nested = (expr & *(expr & op))
    >> e_ref([](It i1, It i2)
{ 
    std::cout << "\nparsed nested: " << std::string(i1, i2); 
});
auto get = (id & "<<")  
    >> e_ref([](It i1, It i2)
{ 
    std::cout << "\nparsed get: " << std::string(i1, i2); 
});
auto var = (nested & id & ">>")  
    >> e_ref([](It i1, It i2)
{ 
    std::cout << "\nparsed var: " << std::string(i1, i2); 
});
auto body = (*(nested & space) | *(var & space) | *(get & space))
     >> e_ref([](It i1, It i2)
{ 
    std::cout << "\nparsed body: " << std::string(i1, i2); 
});
auto program = +(body)
    | r_fail([](It i1, It i2) 
{
    std::cout << "\nparsing failed, parsed portion: " 
        << std::string(i1, i2);
});
// test parser
std::ostringstream text;
text << "2 2 * test >>";
std::string str = text.str();
program(str.begin(), str.end());
```

Comment: That is _a_ problem (that it never terminates), but not the problem the OP reported about. Also, thequestion is clearly about ANTLR and Python, not about C++ and AXE.

Comment: @Bart Kiers: that's pretty rude. I gave both identification of the problem together with the better way of tackling it.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to be rude (we must also have different definitions of "rude", btw). But you _are_ wrong: the problem the OP states (a `MismatchedTokenException`), is not because the body rule never terminates. And as I already mentioned: the OP clearly asks about Python and ANTLR, not about C++ and AXE.

Comment: If the OP had the problem because of the fact that the body rule never terminates, some sort of overflow-exception would have been thrown, not a `MismatchedTokenException`. Like I said: the fact that `body` matches zero or more empty strings is indeed a problem, but not _the_ problem the OP is reporting about.