# ANTLR 3.5.1 (latest 3.x release) with Python runtime 3.1.3 (only available Python runtime)

Tags: python, antlr, antlr3

It looks like 3.5.1 is the latest 3.x version, and 3.1.3 is the only available version (http://www.antlr.org/download/Python/). However, when I try to run the parser using the example, I get a complaint that my runtime version is not compatible with my ANTLR version:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/home/dustin/build/antlr3/antlr_python_runtime-3.1.3 python SimpleCalcParser.py /tmp/lang 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SimpleCalcParser.py", line 231, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "SimpleCalcParser.py", line 220, in main
    lexer = SimpleCalcLexer(char_stream)
  File "/home/dustin/development/antlr/antlr3/hello_world_python/SimpleCalcLexer.py", line 31, in __init__
    super(SimpleCalcLexer, self).__init__(input, state)
  File "/home/dustin/build/antlr3/antlr_python_runtime-3.1.3/antlr3/recognizers.py", line 1072, in __init__
    BaseRecognizer.__init__(self, state)
  File "/home/dustin/build/antlr3/antlr_python_runtime-3.1.3/antlr3/recognizers.py", line 184, in __init__
    self.antlr_version_str))
RuntimeError: ANTLR version mismatch: The recognizer has been generated by V3.0.1, but this runtime is V3.1.3. Please use the V3.0.1 runtime.
```

Can anyone put me on the right path? I doesn't seem like there's much I can do, due to the scarcity of versions available for download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the Python runtime, you **must** use ANTLR 3.1.3 to generate your [Python] lexer and parser.

Download 3.1.3 here: http://www.antlr3.org/download/antlr-3.1.3.jar

The following Q&A provides a working Python example: [ANTLR parsing MismatchedTokenException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359881/antlr-parsing-mismatchedtokenexception)

Comment: Confirmed. Thank you, Bart.