# draw syntax tree with antlr3 generated parser for the Python

Tags: python, antlr

I try to parse C++ source files with antlr3 generated parser for the Python runtime. I need to make some changes in grammar, and i whant to draw syntax tree using generated parser in order to verify that my changes is correct, how can i do this?

Simple sample, syntax tree of which i need:

```
int main (){
  int a = 4;
  return a;
}
```

PS: sorry for my english.

Comment: Use https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

Comment: You will need to clarify a bit. What are you parsing: some language with an ANTLR3 generated parser for the Python runtime? Or are you parsing Python source files with an ANTLR3/ANTLR4 generated parser? Please post your grammar and any source files you are using to test things. As your question is now, it will likely be closed and deleted, just like your previous one. If expressing this in English is too difficult, and Portuguese happens to be your first language, you could ask your question [here](http://pt.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Thanks for remarks. I corrected question, hope now it became clearer. Thanks for link, but my first language is Albanian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there does not exist a way to draw an AST from the output of an ANTLR 3 parse using a Python library/app.

Here is a way to print a level order traversal of the AST on your console (assuming your grammar is called `Cpp.g`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import antlr3
from antlr3 import *
from antlr3.tree import *
from CppLexer import *
from CppParser import *

def print_level_order(tree, indent):
  print '{0}{1}'.format('   '*indent, tree.text)
  for child in tree.getChildren():
    print_level_order(child, indent+1)

input = """
  int main (){
    int a = 4;
    return a;
  }
"""
char_stream = antlr3.ANTLRStringStream(input)
lexer = CppLexer(char_stream)
tokens = antlr3.CommonTokenStream(lexer)
parser = CppParser(tokens)
tree = parser.parse().tree 
print_level_order(tree, 0)
```

The snippet came from: [ANTLR parsing MismatchedTokenException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359881/antlr-parsing-mismatchedtokenexception)

Comment: Thanks, it helped. But i use parser.translation_unit() instead parser.parse(), because parser.parse() was not defined.